# Get data from sheet depending on cell value

Tags: spreadsheet

I have a spread sheet that has multiple sheets, the first being "Main Sheet". The subsequent sheet names are the same as the values in column A of "Main Sheet".

Eg:
Main Sheet
Column A5 = 12345
Column A6 = 23456

I want to get the value of cell "Main Sheet"(B5) from sheet "12345"(B10) (the value in "Main Sheet"(A5)) and the value of cell "Main Sheet"(B6) from sheet "23456"(B10).

As the "Main Sheet" is continuously growing, I need to do this by a formula.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your notation makes it seem like you're not using MS Excel, but if you ARE, this should solve your problem.

You will want to use the INDIRECT function. It will turn a string into a reference to a cell.

This means that you can do something like the following (in B1 of Main Sheet):

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'", 'Main Sheet'!A1, "'!B10"))
```

Assuming that:

```
'Main Sheet'!A1 == abc123
```

The formula will give you the contents of:

```
'abc123'!B10
```

Comment: I am using MS Excel, and this is exactly what I need. Many thanks.